# Viewing MVT tile with its buffer in QGIS without clipping it

Tags: qgis, import, mapbox-vector-tile

When viewing a single MVT tile in QGIS, it seems QGIS is clipping all geometries to the tile's extent. In other words, if the tile's extent is 4096, any coordinates that are less than 0 or more than 4095 are hidden in the view.  In some cases, especially data validation, it would be good to see the buffer around the tile too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the .pbf file through "Layer - Add vector layer". That way you can use advanced driver options.

Find the "Clip" setting from the options and select "No" instead of "<Default>". These advanced driver specific options are not available if data are added with the QGIS Browser or by drag-and-drop.

[image]

What it means is explained in [gdal driver documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/mvt.html)

> **CLIP=YES/NO**: Whether to clip geometries of vector features to tile
> extent. Generators of vector tiles will typically create geometries
> with a small buffer beyond the tile extent so that geometries
> intersecting several tiles can be unioned back. Defaults to YES so
> that that buffer is removed and geometries are clipped exactly to the
> tile extent.

Comment: Thanks!  Could you point to where this can be modified in QGIS?  I found GDAL options/vector, but there are no settings for MVT driver, just enable/disable checkbox.

Comment: Layer - Add vector layer - select the .pbf file -> expand the Options line.

Comment: ah, thanks!  I was not even aware there is this method of adding - I always just browsed to the file using "browser" panel, and double clicked the file to add its layers. Seems very counter-intuitive that there is this other big way of doing the same thing with lots of options :( Thanks for your help, could you add that comment to your answer too for others?